# Audio through socket

Tags: java, sockets, audio, lan

So I'm trying to make a server that open a socket to stream music for one client.
The problem that I have is that I have no idea how to make the server play the music and how to read the bytes dynamically with the client.

Right now, I've tried to use the java audio system without any results.

Keep in mind that I need the server to play the music and not the client because the server is an audio player that can play/pause etc.

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: Have you look at the [Java Sound Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/)?

Comment: Well I looked at it, but the problem is that I am a total newbie in sockets and sound so I have no idea how to stream it and I can't find anything in the documentation to help me either :/
I mostly don't know how to make a custom dataline to use for the server socket

Comment: Why do you think you need to make a custom dataline?

Comment: To send raw bytes while playing an instance of Clip. Is there a better way ?

Comment: I can only suggest you re-read the tutorial. Too broad.